What is the name of this military coup comedy set in a Latin American country?
I watched this comedy movie several years ago about a military coup in a Latin American country. Several young men take a city with tanks, all but the last objective, the government palace. The most important politicians are inside. They had no option but to surrender.
However, they make a tricky negotiation with the rebels and keep with the power and control of the government, thus frustrating the coup. One of the politicians at some point says something like, "They are too young as to bribe them."
That's all I know. I have tried a lot of ChatGPT without luck since there seems to be a lot of comedies about military coups in Latin American countries.
What's the name of this movie?

Please review Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions and [edit] in anything else you can recall

Where did you see the movie? What language was it in? You saw it a few years ago, but how old was the movie - was it a new release at the time, or older?

Also, what movies have you checked and ruled out?

Providing a quote (even a partial quote) makes finding the thing a doddle, courtesy of the Internet Movie quote database; https://www.quodb.com/search/young%20bribe?advance-search=false&keywords=young%20bribe

This is April Captains (AKA Capitães de Abril) (2000).

Story of the 1974 coup that overthrew the right-wing Portuguese dictatorship--which continued the fascist policies of long-time dictator Antonio Salazar--and of two young army captains who were involved in it.

Not really a comedy, but it does contain the line in question;

"They are too young to be bribed." (around timestamp 01:24:44)





Thank you for IDing despite my misinformation, thanks a lot!
